# How to add both top and bottom navigation tab using react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

currently, I am able to get the individual top and bottom tabs but don't know how to use both in my app.

Comment: call the bottom tab navigator stack on intial loading of top tab navigator stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `createBottomTabNavigator` in a `createStackNavigator` and export it:

```
const Bottom = createBottomTabNavigator({
    item1: {screen: Screen1},
    item2: {screen: Screen2},
    },{
        initialRouteName: "item1",
    }
)

export default createStackNavigator({
    tabs: Bottom,
    item3: Screen3,
})
```